# Do gravitational redshift depends on reference frames?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, reference-frames, observers, gravitational-redshift

I just want to know is the effect of redshift depending on the frames of reference or the photon really does lose energy when it escaped from a gravitational well? Imagine a spaceship is shooting a laser at a specific wavelength is caught in a gravitational well, would the crews notice any change in the wavelength as the spaceship that's still shooting laser escapes from the gravitational well?

Comment: I would say it does to the extent that it needs to be going towards the observer to be able to measure it. I  know this probably doesn't answer your question though. Is your question, what happens to the laser as recieved by a second ship directly in front of the first ship?

Answer (score 1):

It does, If you know the expression for shift
$$\frac{\nu_R}{\nu_E}=\frac{p_0(B)}{p_0(A)}\left[\frac{g_{00}(A)}{g_{00}(B)}\right]^{1/2}$$
See [General Relativity: An introduction to Physicists](https://www.amazon.in/General-Relativity-Introduction-Physicists-Hobson/dp/0521829518) Appendix 9A for the proof.
[image]

It's clear from here that different observers have different $p_0$, and therefore have a different shifts.

---

It might be helpful to watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DrBQg_n2Uo&t=317s) veritesium video.

Comment: No link to video!

Comment: @m4r35n357 Forgot to add, Thanks for pointing.